# Enable OJDBC Logging on JBoss

Tags: oracle, logging, jdbc

I'm facing database connection issue when using `ojdbc6.jar`. Therefore, I would like to enable logging by using ojdbc6_g.jar.

I am using `JBoss AS 7.1`.

How to add these Java options:

```
-Doracle.jdbc.Trace=true 
-Djava.util.logging.config.file
```

Do I have to add to `Eclipse` or `JBoss` or `Oracle` database ? My guess would be `Eclipse`.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- the JDBC driver has to be in the classpath of the JBOSS server otherwise JBOSS could not be able to find the oracle Server
- this could also be a network issue
- also you mix several concept in once line ; weird

so we need more details about your problem, for example errors ; logs etc.